# Ember error when json response root key is singular

Tags: json, ember.js

I am getting an Ember error when the response json root is singular.

json response:

```
{"subscription": {"id": "1"}}
```

error:

`Assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key subscription but you have no mapping for it`

model:

```
App.Subscription
```

If I pass a plural root key `subscriptions` in the json response, it works fine. I don't think I should have to do this though since the singular version is default behavior for active
_model_serializers if there is only one resource to send.

Is this a bug in Ember or should I be doing something for this to be supported?

Answer (score 2):

What might help is to define plurals on your adapter. So in the case of a model called `App.Subscription` this could look like this:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend();
App.Adapter.configure('plurals', { "subscription": "subscription" });
```

**Edit**

As for the `.json` one possible solution might be to hook into the `buildURL` function of your `RESTAdapter` and adding the `.json` suffix yourself. This could look something like this:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  buildURL: function(record, suffix) {
    var url = this._super(record, suffix);
    return url + ".json";
  }
})
```

This would make a request to `http://localhost:4000//subscription.json`

Hope it helps.

Comment: If I do that, then the endpoint url is changed to a singular: `http://localhost:4000//subscription.json` and results in a 404

Comment: @flynfish edited my answer, is this what you where looking for?

Comment: I was already adding `.json` to the url as you suggested. I meant that it changes to `subscription.json` in the singular form rather than keeping the plural `subscriptions.json`. i.e. my endpoint is `/subscriptions`, not `/subscription`